# Почтовые ящики на хостинге

Tags: домен, email, хостинг

Добрый день. В поисках нового хостинга я столкнулся с таким вопросом:

**Зачем на странице тарифных планов хостинга пишут количество "Почтовых ящиков", если можно запросто на mail.yandex.ru подключить свой домен к этой почте?**
И главное то, что разница в количестве очень большая. Например, на самом дорогом тарифном плане этого хостинга можно создать всего 300 почтовых ящиков, в то время как на бесплатной Яндекс.Почте до 1000 штук.

Большое спасибо за внятный ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

думаю, правильный ответ будет такой - так сложилось исторически. С другой стороны, почтовые ящики потребляют кое-какие ресурсы (дисковое пространство к примеру). И если выделяют 1Гб под сайт, под почтовые ящики тоже нужно что то...

а Яндекс... он зарабатывает на другом. Поэтому может.

Comment: Что ж вы в ответы не написали это? :) Мне больше всего ваш ответ понравился.

Comment: Сделал ответом. Надеюсь, никто не будет против)

Answer (score 0):

Наверное на оплаченном хостинге не будет рекламы яндекса )

Comment: Наверное в Яндексе можно попробовать зайти в настройки ящика и снять галочку "показывать рекламу". Или вообще не ходить через веб-интерфейс.

Answer (score 0):

Количество ящиков не у всех ограниченно! У "апплетек", например, без лимита! А тот же Яндекс предупреждает, что бесплатно только пока...

Comment: Здравствуйте. А где вы прочитали об этом? Ссылку дайте, если не сложно.
И потом, у google.почты тоже есть подключение своего домена, бесплатно.

Comment: Подключал один ящик к Яндексу, по ходу настройки Яндекс сказал, что услуга предоставляется, но халява в будущем не обещается, слово в слово не помню.